# How to swap values of args in JS

Tags: javascript

I tried to swap the values of args in JS Function. My function looks like this:

```
function swapValues(x,y){ 
return (y,x);}
```

And I call this function as below:

```
console.log(swapValues(5,10))
```

I expected for the output to give me  `(10,5)` but it's `5`
So, can you please let me know why it's 5 there?

Comment: Because that's the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: that means I can not return 2 values from a function while using comma?

Comment: A function can only return one value. That value can be e.g. an _array_, though.

Comment: `return [y, x]`, not `return (y, x)`.

Comment: okay, got it :D